# How to run an infinite loop function in django celery on startup?

Tags: python, django, celery

I want to make a django website that will display data from the database. And the parser will add information to this database. And I want to make it so that during the launch of the site it also starts (only once) and parses information in an endless loop. Or make it so that django celery calls a function, but only if this function is not already called.

And I would like to know how to do it.

I tried to write this in the view.py file

```
from .tasks import my_task
my_task.delay()
```

But as I understand it, this is bad because when I wrote any command in the terminal, I opened a browser for parsing